Elasticsearch - How to get a match based on the largest number of them
I have index structure like this
{
    "attr_id": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "attr_name": [
        "name1",
        "name2"
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "value": [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ]
},

settings structure:
{
    "analyzer": {
        "r_R": {
            "char_filter": [
                "dash_filter",
                "big_dash_filter",
                "colon_filter",
                "open_bracket_filter",
                "close_bracket_filter",
                "dot_filter",
                "comma_filter",
                "opening_double_quote",
                "closing_double_quote",
                "number_filter",
                "double_quote"
            ],
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "stopwords_ru",
                "my_length_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        },
        "search_anal": {
            "char_filter": [
                "dash_filter",
                "big_dash_filter",
                "colon_filter",
                "open_bracket_filter",
                "close_bracket_filter",
                "dot_filter",
                "comma_filter",
                "opening_double_quote",
                "closing_double_quote",
                "number_filter",
                "double_quote"
            ],
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "type": "custom"
        }
    }
}

, where each char filter transfrom symbol to space, mapping structure:
{
    "properties": {
        "attr_id": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "attr_name": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "global_id": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "value": {
            "analyzer": "r_R",
            "search_analyzer": "search_anal",
            "term_vector": "yes",
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}

The problem is that when I search the index, hits with one value are returned before those with multiple values. for example, if I search for “hello world”, then the phrase “hello” is given to me first, and only then “hello world”.
I search using the value field. Is it possible that tokenization occurs not only on the "value" field, but also on others in the index? Perhaps if attr_name is set to "world", then this gives its weight. If this is the problem, how can I avoid it?
That's how i'am searching
FunctionScoreQueryBuilder functionScoreQuery = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(
QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("value", searchValue).boost(10))
.should(QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("value", (String) searchValue).boost(5))
.should(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("value", searchValue).boost(2)))
.scoreMode(FunctionScoreQuery.ScoreMode.SUM);

            searchQuery.withQuery(functionScoreQuery)
                    .withFilter(filters)
                    .withHighlightFields(field)
                    .withTrackTotalHits(true)
                    .withPageable(PageRequest.of(pageOffset, limit));

Actually resulted "hello", and only then "hello world"

If you're searching for neighboring tokens you can also add match_phrase in your should array with a bigger boost.
